# unfound entry point deflateSetHeader at zlib1.dll

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk

I'm trying to install GTK+ 2.16, using Code::Blocks, I set the "gtk" environnement variable and everything. It compiles successfully, the problem rises in run-time when it says "No entry point found for procedure deflateSetHeader in the dynamic library zlib1.dll".

Anyone has an idea about this ? Is this some kind of bug that should be reported ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have an old version of zlib installed that doesn't contain the deflateSetHeader call. You should locate your dll and replace it with a newer version and/or reinstall a newer version of gtk.

Since Code::Blocks requires this call in zlib1.dll (the source of the failure) it will not be able to run without it so you must provide it with a version of the dll that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to install StarDict-editor in my Windows XP computer.

I got the installer stardict-editor-3.0.1.rar from http://code.google.com/p/stardictproject/downloads/list
and tried to install StarDict-editor without GTK but was impossible because a lot of messages reporting .dll files missing.

Finally the solution was:

1. Install first the GTK+ for Windows Runtime Environment from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-win/?abmode=1
   In the installation options mark an option saying something like "install dll files..."
2. Try again to install stardict-editor.exe
3. Then I got the mentioned error message: "The procedure entry point deflateSetHeader could not be located in the dynamic link library zlib1.dll"
4. I looked in my computer for zlib1.dll files and find several versions.
5. Choose from the list of files, the more recently created zlib1.dll. Copy this file and paste the copy in the path: c:\Windows\system32 (this is for Windows XP)
6. Now, try again the installation stardict-editor.exe
7. StarDict-editor installed and working ok, it seems.